Will this Itô-process have this property?(Will the process be in $L^2$)?
Assume you have an Itô-process :
$dX_t = \mu_tdt+\sigma_tdB_t, t\le T$
Normally we must have that $P(\int_0^T \sigma_t^2 dt<\infty)=1$. But assume we have the stronger condition $E[\int_0^T\sigma_t^2 dt ]<\infty$.
Assume you have a $f \in C^{1,2}[0,T]$.  Then Itô's lemma says that $f(t,X_t)$ is an Itô-process and it also gives the dynamics $d f(t,X_t) = \mu_t^*dt+\sigma_t^*dB_t$. Itô's lemma says that we must have that $P(\int_0^T \sigma_t^{*2} dt<\infty)=1$.(Or else the stochastic integral would not make sense.)
But do we now in this case have $E[\int_0^T\sigma_t^{*2} dt ]<\infty$?

Let $X=W$, $W$ standard Brownian motion so that $\mu=0,\sigma=1$. We have $E[\int_0^T\sigma_t^2dt]=T<\infty$. Consider $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and the process $Y_t=e^{W_t^2}$. Then by Ito's formula we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}dY_t&=f'(W_t)dW_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(W_t)dt\\
&=2W_te^{W_t^2}dW_t+(...)\\
&=\sigma^*_tdW_t+(...)\\
\end{aligned}$$
and by Tonelli-Fubini $E[\int_0^T(\sigma^*_t)^2dt]=4\int_0^TE[W_t^2e^{2W_t^2}]dt$. However:
$$E[W_t^2e^{2W_t^2}]\propto\int_\mathbb{R}y^2e^{y^2(2-\frac{1}{2t})}dy=\infty,\forall t\geq 1/4$$
so if $T>1/4$ we have $E[\int_0^T(\sigma^*_t)^2dt]=\infty$.
